# Hibernate - How to Object and load foreign key objects in one SQL query?

Tags: hibernate

I would like to load my objects from database with foreign key object ( relation One-to-One )
What I'm trying to achieve is to use my object like this.

```
parent.getChildrenFk().getName();
```

I know that I can do it this two ways

```
1. Lazy load

...
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM parent").addEntity(Parent.class);
List<Parent> list = sqlQuery.list();
for(Parent p : list){
String name = p.getChildFk().getName();
}
return list;
...
```

Disadvantage of this solution is SQL query for each child ( I have more than 10000 Parent objects).

```
2.Second solutions is to get list of Objects[] 
obj[0] is Parent, and obj[1] is Child

SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM parent INNER JOIN child ch ON parent.child_fk = child.child_id").addEntity(Parent.class).addEntity(Child.class);
return sqlQuery.list();
```

Disadvantage of this solution is that I can't access my Object this way **parent.getChildrenFk().getName();** Is there is any way to load Parent objects with Child objects in one query to have access to child obj as I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to query your database is to use HQL. SQL is useful as a backup strategy, when HQL can't do what you need.

You should definitely read [the documentation about HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql), because it seems you completely ignore its existence, and HQL is a key part of Hibernate (and JPA).

To get a parent and its child in a single HQL query, assuming they're is an association from parent to child, and the field is named `child`, you just need

```
select p from Parent p left join fetch p.child
```